# Removing a seat post spacer

Tags: saddle

I am trying to get an old Raleigh SC 40 bike back to riding condition. The seat post doesn't tighten at all and the culprit is that the spacer sleeve is stuck well into the frame.

In order to get a new seat post, I would assume that this spacer needs to be removed.  Any ideas for easy removal.  I tried to wedge a small flat screwdriver between the spacer and the frame but still can't loosen it. Looking at it I would assume that it is aluminum (definitely metal). Use WD 40? Then what!?! Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the spacer straight or does it have a narrow 90° edge that sits on top of the seat tube? If it has an edge you may grip that firmly with a (small sized) vise-grip at the slot and 'roll' it inwards. Any way penetrating oil and a two days' wait is also helpful.

Comment: Adding a photo to your question would help demonstrate what you see.  Could be that its an integral part of the bike and not a spacer.  Aluminium feels "warmer" than steel, and does not respond to a magnet.   Are you positive that the seatpost is the right size for this bike?  There are literally a dozen different common sizes and they differ by 0.1 mm

Comment: How far in is it? I know I could make an extractor but describing how to on SE would be too much. A common solution is to get a new spacer and just shove the old spacer down enough to make room for the new spacer

Comment: I just added two pictures to help identify the issue I am facing.  Thanks for taking the time to help me out.

Comment: I wonder if you could pull it out with a [plasterboard /drywall toggle screw](https://www.screwfix.com/p/easyfix-spring-toggles-5-x-50mm-20-pack/4257x) possibly with studding in place of the screw.

Comment: @ben is there a vertical slot in the spacer at all?  Or is it a pipe/tube ?

Answer (score 2):

It’s much easier to push than it is to pull.

So I suggest you remove your bottom bracket entirely and then push the spacer all the way down into the bottom bracket space where it can be then cut, folded, spindled, and mutilated.

Appropriately sized wooden dowels or PVC tubing would be your best bet if you didn’t want to mar the seat tube. Very long handled minus screwdrivers can be used if you don’t care anymore. An aluminum spacer may have cold welded itself to a steel seat tube and in those cases, chemical or thermal assistance may also be needed.

Ps. I don’t actually see a **seat post clamp** on your bike in your pictures and so I’m assuming you do actually have one.

Comment: Usually there is a drainage hole at the very bottom. Another option would be to use a thin and sturdy rod (e.g. a spare spoke) to poke through this hole and try to push the spacer out.

Comment: The drainage holes I’m familiar with are very small, 1 mm or so in diameter. A spoke might fit but would not be stiff enough to exert any significant force when pushed from below.....

Comment: +1 for "cut, folded, spindled, and mutilated"